# Is there anyway I can test in junit a method that tells if a character is repeating

Tags: java, junit

I need to test a method that checks if a character is repeating in JUnit and when I run the test, its sayinthing expected: false    .

```
public boolean isRepeated(char ch) {

        ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
        for (char letter : guessLetter) {// guessLetter is a character ArrayList 
            if (letter == ch) {
                return true;

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

@Test
    void test() {
        game game=new game();
        boolean res=false;
        char c='A';
        res =game.isRepeated(c);
        String words = new String("AAAA");
        ArrayList<Character> guessLetter = new 
ArrayList<Character>();
        for ( int i=0; i<words.length(); i ++) {
            guessLetter.add(words.charAt(i));

        }

        assertEquals(res, guessLetter);


    }
```

Comment: @Progman - I feel like there's plenty of code here to at least come to a reasonable answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few issues here, but let's start with the low-hanging fruit.

**Your order of operations is wrong.**  You want to have your list set up *before* you run your test.

Now let's talk through the issue that you have with the actual test data.  From what you've shown, it is unclear whether or not `guessLetter` is either a field in `game` or if it's a field in your test class, or whether or not your test class is defined in the same class as your actual code (and you should ***NOT*** be doing that!!).

#### Case 1: `game` is the owner of the field `guessLetter`

Move your test data initialization before you invoke your test by providing the test data you want to use.  If you lack a setter for `guessLetter`, then add one in.

```
@Test
void test() {
    String words = "AAAA";
    ArrayList<Character> guessLetter = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
        guessLetter.add(words.charAt(i));

    }
    game game = new game();
    game.setGuessLetter(guessLetter);

    assertEquals(true, game.isRepeated('A'));
}
```

Notice how there's no superfluous variables here either; everything we want to test is apparent and crystal clear.

#### Case 2:  `game` is not the owner of `guessLetter`

Refactor your code such that `game` ***is*** the owner of `guessLetter`, and refer to Case 1.

#### Case 3:  Your test code is in the same class as your actual code

Refactor your code such that you have two separate classes; one to test the code and one to run the code.  Then, refer to Case 1.

Comment: This is very good, but I wouldn't quite say that everything is crystal clear. I would move the creation of the list from the string to a helper method, and declare guessLetter to be a `List<Character>` (code to the interface, not the implementation).

Comment: @DavidConrad:  I agree but I didn't want to overload them with too much at once.

Comment: guessLetter is a field in the game. where did you get that setGuessLetter?

Comment: @KalidDiriye:  I conjured it up.  You need to have a way to put the letters you build into your class, and a setter is the fastest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`res` has the type boolean. `guessLetter` has the type ArrayList. They will therefore never be equal, and your test will always fail.

Comment: because the method is boolean. how can i solve it ?

Comment: Also, `guessLetter` hasn't been set yet when `isRepeated` is called, at least as far as we can tell from what we've been shown, and `isRepeated` doesn't check for *repeated* letters, only the *presence* of a given `char`.